# Alter SQLite DB structure when upgrading app

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite

I would like to use the EntityFramework model to connect to an embedded SQLite database in my C# application. Everything works fine but as this is the first version of the software I expect future changes to have a cause changes to the structure of the database.

I am concerned since I do not know when a user would upgrade from ver.1 to say ver 2. how to alter the strucure of the embedded database and of course save the existing data.

Anybody else run into this issue, and how did you solve it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a complete upgrade framework in C# to handle this type of problem. It served me well in a big client project and saved me tons of work in the process.

You can read about it [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/sqlite_upgrade.aspx). It is in the public domain so you can use it for your projects (including commercial projects) without paying anything :-)

If you have any specific questions I'll be happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

I got an idea but an unsure if it is a correct approach: 
 write an small external tool to alter(upgrade) the database structure, and run this in the application installer.

What do you think about such an approach ?